# Class as parameter in Spring Data's query method

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I've got such method in Spring Data's repository:

```
public interface GameSessionRepository extends JpaRepository<GameSession, Long> {
  
  @Query("SELECT gs FROM GameSession gs WHERE TYPE(gs) = :gameSessionType")
    <T extends GameSession> Optional<T> findActive(
            @Param("gameSessionType") Class<T> gameSessionType
    );
}
```

but the invocation gives me an exception: `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : gameSessionType` .

For context, `GameSession` is an abstract entity class with two concrete implementations: `QuizGameSession` and `TranslationGameSession`.

My question is: is it possible to achieve this kind of signature in Spring Data?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
It is not possible to achieve the signature of your GameSessionRepository interface in Spring Data as-is. The reason is that Spring Data JPA does not support dynamic type parameters in queries.

It may be possible to :

```
public interface GameSessionRepository extends JpaRepository<GameSession, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT gs FROM GameSession gs WHERE TYPE(gs) = :gameSessionType")
    <T extends GameSession> Optional<T> findActive(
            @Param("gameSessionType") String gameSessionType
    );
}
```

Comment: I wonder if Spring data supports the generic/dynamic return type like that, i.e. would it actually return the sub-type of GameSession.

Comment: You mean to return the concrete type? I believe it will.